# Enforce Unique Publisher/Producer on a Azure Service Bus Topic

Tags: azureservicebus, publish-subscribe, azure-servicebus-topics

Using Azure Service Bus, is there any way to restrict the ability to publish on a topic to a single producer/publisher? I want to enforce a one-to-many publishing scenario but haven't found a way to restrict the ability to publish to just a single producing system.

Using SAS I can restrict a publisher's ability to publish to a single topic, but that's not the solution I'm looking for. The publisher may produce messages on multiple topics, but for each of those topics, that publisher should be the sole producer and the service bus should reject attempts to publish on that topic by other producers. Is this possible?

Comment: No; the service does not support an option to request exclusive publishing access to an entity.  Using narrowly scoped auth is the only control.

Comment: @JesseSquire comment should have been the answer.